# How can I use localStorage in php with AJAX to update my database?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, local-storage

I need to use a *localStorage* value in a PHP file to update values in my database. I know that I need ajax to achieve this, I can't get it to work.

My *localStorage* item is named option and it exists (checked in browser and stored the value in a *div*)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "activity.php",
            data: { storageValue: localStorage.getItem('option') },
            success: function(data){
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    });
```

**PHP Example:**

```
$option = $_POST['storageValue'];
mysql_query("...SET x = '".$option."'...");
echo 'Update complete';
```

I dont see any post data nor do I get a response.

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like you have error in your JS. You can't have a `;` character inside the `data: {...}` part.

Comment: ty, i removed the ; but my php file still doesn't return anything or show the alert :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your page:**

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" value="thedatayouwanttopost" id="option"/>
</form>
<script src="Your_Js_File.js"></script>
```

**Your JS file:**

```
document.getElementById('option').submit(); // This submits the form

var storageValue = $('#option').val(); // This gets the value of the form once it has been posted to the .php file

$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "activity.php",
            data: { storageValue:storageValue },
            success: function(data){
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    return false; // This stops the page from refreshing
    });
```

**Your PHP file to callback the data to AJAX and display the alert (activity.php):**

```
...
$option = $_POST['storageValue']; // This is the post value of your hidden input on your page

mysql_query("...SET x = '".$option."'...");
?><input type="hidden" id="option" value="<?php echo $option; ?>"><?
// The input above posts the value of 'option' on your page back to your Ajax and spits out the request.
    ...
```

Comment: ok thank you, i assume the input should trigger my alert? even if i add this to my code it still returns nothing or updates my database. and i still can't see the post data in my browser.

Comment: Is the .php file that you're pulling $option from called 'activity.php'?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if it's still not working.

Comment: yes, i double checked, the file where my JS/Ajax script is executed is named: localstorage.php and the file i call in the ajax script has no typo

Comment: So it's like so:

The page you want the alert on <script src="AjaxScriptHere.js"></script>, then within the Ajax, the url is the .php script that you are pulling the PHP from?

Comment: in my script i want to send my localStorage value via post to the activity.php file where i execute my db script. after the update completed i want to trigger the alert

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to call the .php file containing your $option variable on the page you want to display the alert on. In the code above we can post $option into the hidden input field, that is then taken by Ajax and spits out the alert on success.

I'll just edit my code again to return the function as false. Because you're echoing 'Update Complete', it's taking the user to that file. We need to ask Ajax to spit out the alert without taking the user to the file.

Comment: sorry but i don't get your point. you assume i have the localStorage variable in a div with id: result? thats not the case. the alert is also just a placeholder so that i can see my script ecexutes. in fact i dont want to return anything, i just want to update my database with the localStorage variable, but the user shouldn't see anything. i also don't understand when you say i dont need to call the php file? thats where my update happens?

Comment: Think of Ajax as the link between the page you want to display the alert on. The URL is set in the Ajax file to grab the POST data, which is set in our hidden input field.

Try changing the URL to the file where $option is defined. If it doesn't work I'll have a re-think.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is $option being posted by the user, or are you trying to get the data from the db?

Comment: i think im wrong but $option should be the data i send from my ajax script to the .php file. (is it even possible to send data with ajax without a form?)

Comment: Aha, there's your problem.

Comment: I thought you had the user 'POST'ing to Ajax. No data is going into your POST to do anything with.

Comment: no sorry, thats my fault. i just want to send data via ajax to the .php file where i use the localStorage data as $option

Comment: What is the data that you want to send?

Comment: localStorage.getItem('option')

Comment: But $_POST is a post made by the user, so you need to post something

Comment: Alright, so i need a form to send data in my ajax script? So i have to make a workaround so the user doesn't need to click or type something because i have the needed information already in the localStorage.

Comment: I've fixed the answer for you.